# VBA: how to pass a string array from an function

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I can't handle the array in combination with an function very well.
i want to edit an string array in an external function.
(also redim it later with preserve)
But in my test i get an error:

```
 Sub test()
        Dim test() As Variant
        Dim testnew() As Variant
        ReDim Preserve test(1 To 4)
        test(1) = "one"
        test(2) = "two"
        test = testfunc(test)
        Debug.Print test(3)
    End Sub
    
Function testfunc(test() As Variant) As Variant
test(3) = "three"
End Function
```

Comment: You don't have a string array, and you are successfully passing it to the function. The error is on assigning to `test`, which should not be done in the first place. "I get an error" is not a helpful description. Replace `test = testfunc(test)` with `testfunc test`.

Comment: I'd make `testfunc` a `Sub` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning your array:

```
Sub test()
    Dim test() As Variant
    Dim testnew() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve test(1 To 4)
    test(1) = "one"
    test(2) = "two"
    test = testfunc(test)
    Debug.Print test(3)
End Sub
    
Function testfunc(test() As Variant) As Variant
    test(3) = "three"
    testfunc = test
End Function
```

or as the comments have stated change to sub and do byRef:

```
Sub test()
    Dim test() As Variant
    Dim testnew() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve test(1 To 4)
    test(1) = "one"
    test(2) = "two"
    testfunc test
    Debug.Print test(3)
End Sub
    
Sub testfunc(ByRef test() As Variant)
    test(3) = "three"
End Sub
```

Comment: It was already byref though.

Comment: @GSerg yes, but when using sub I like to spell it out, it alleviates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Return the array *by reference*:

```vb
Public Sub test()

    Dim test() As Variant
    Dim testnew() As Variant

    ReDim Preserve test(1 To 4)
    test(1) = "one"
    test(2) = "two"
    testfunc test

    Debug.Print test(3)
    
End Sub
    
Public Sub testfunc(test() As Variant)
    
    test(3) = "three"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Right. Return, I meant.